# How to redirect url for CreateView in views.py

Tags: django

1. `class A_modelCreateView(CreateView)`in views.py
2. `path('create/'),view.A_modelCreateView().as_view(),name='create'` in urls.py
3. build an HTML as form for A_model form but not in its default directory(my_app/A_model.form)

Is there filled parameter somewhere for redirect the url you want?

Comment: Yes, that is the `success_url`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a `CreateView` has as one of its baseclasses a the `FormMixin`. This `FormMixin` class has a [**`success_url`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.success_url).

You can add a real url, or work with [**`reverse_lazy`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse_lazy) to calculate the URL based on the name of a view. For example:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

class A_modelCreateView(CreateView):
    success_url = reverse_lazy('overview_page')
    # ...
```

where `overview_page` is here the name of a hypothetical view.

If you do *not* specify a `success_url` in a `CreateView` or `UpdateView`, it will take the `get_absolute_url` of the model object that is created/updated, if the model has such method. For more information, see the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms).